# How to enable click outside dialog box

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript

I have a running Angular 9 application and I have created custom dialog box. As of now, once the dialog box opens, I can only click on the buttons which is inside the dialog box.

dialog.component.html

```
<div class="modal">
<div class="modal-body">
    <ng-template #content></ng-template>
</div>
```

dialog.component.css

```
.modal {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
  }

  .modal-body{
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 50%;
    min-width: 50%;
    top: 100px;
    left: 0px;
  }
```

I want to achieve a behavior in which I want to enable click outside the dialog box:

1. **Button which is inside the dialog box** (*Close button* in the below image) and the **button which is outside the dialog box** (*Click Me* button in the below image) to be clickable.
2. Links (**Click Here to Open New Modal**) to be clickable which is outside dialog box

I want a generic solution which should work for every click( button, links, texts etc..) outside and inside dialog box. Please help me on this.

[image]

Stackblitz demo:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/dialog-box-overlay

Comment: If u have backdrop close it, and make z-index level of button same with modal

Comment: I tried giving the z-index of button same as modal, but its not working

Comment: Can u create stackblitz

Comment: Stackblitz demo: [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dialog-box-overlay)

Comment: I added answer @asif905

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why click outside don't work now is because `div class="modal"` works as overlay for application. If you don't want to change current html, you can use css solution for this:

Add `pointer-events: none;` style for modal backdrop (it's your `div class="modal"`)

Add `pointer-events: auto;` for modal itselt (it's your `div class="modal-body"`)

Answer (score 1):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/dialog-box-overlay-fphmxb

By using css you can add `z-index` to the button to make the button come above the backdrop and make it clickable:

```
.btn {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: I have updated my question to provide generic solution for all the clicks ( buttons, texts, links etc..). Can you please help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I added stackblitz example